# Sending Auth token in URQL query

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, urql

I'm trying to send the token inside URQL token but there is no method or description in the docs. I've the token stored in my localStorage using `localStorage.set()` method.
Anyone has any idea how to send the auth token inside query or header?

I tried sending the auth using header and bearer option, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Tokens are usually transmitted through the `Authorization` request header, in a format recognized/expected by your GraphQL back-end (usually in the form `Authorization: Bearer <token>`). You can do this during client creation/setup through the `fetchOptions` option (as this will indeed be passed on internally to fetch when making calls to your back-end).

Say your token is available and stored under `localStorage.set("myToken", token)`, then you would set up your client like this:

```js
const client = createClient({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql', // <- your back-end URL
  fetchOptions: () => {
    const token = localStorage.get("myToken");
    return {
      headers: { authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '' },
    };
  },
});
```

See [URQL's client setup documentation for Svelte](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/basics/svelte/#setting-up-the-client) for reference.

An alternative, more advanced option would be to make use of the [Authentication exchange](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/advanced/authentication/) as part of the exchange chain you can use in an URQL setup (along with caching, dedup, etc.). I have not experimented with it myself, but it looks fairly straightforward if somewhat more complex.